# inverse of a binary matrix modulo 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, cryptography, binary

All operation are modulo 2. I want to calculate the inverse of a matrix. Is there any easy way to do that? I have tried the usual method of finding determinant and all that.

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way. Can you give your matrix here? Also, read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619982/finding-the-determinant-of-an-n-times-n-matrix-and-the-inverse?rq=1).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280522/how-to-find-inverse-of-a-matrix-in-bbb-z-5).

Comment: Finding the determinant is the *hard* way to find the inverse of a matrix (if the matrix is bigger than $2\times2$). Gaussian elimination is much better, and works just fine modulo 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse of binary matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627634/inverse-of-binary-matrix)

Comment: @ManoharsinhRana that matrix is not invertible because it has two rows that are identical meaning it's singular.